# Any value to "Remote Disc" on a laptop that has an optical drive?

Tags: optical-drive, remote-disc

According to [this article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2002127):

> I just got off the phone with applecare support.
>  It IS an error,
>   the Remote Disc icon is not supposed to be there. It is only meant to
>   be installed on the macbook air. It seems like apple by mistake
>   included it on the Mac mini install DVD's.

[Confirmed by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203973) (sort of):

> If your Mac already has a built-in optical drive, or an external
>   optical drive connected, you won't see the Remote Disc feature appear
>   in the Finder or other apps.

Since the first article mentions it appeared in 10.5.6 (or earlier), it seems odd that something Apple has called a bug would still be in 10.13.1.

I know how to remove and re-create it, and it could be useful if my optical drive fails.  But I know several other ways of using remote discs.

*Is there any value to this if I **do** have a working optical drive?*

Comment: Opinion based?  If someone can name another use, the answer is clearly yes.  If not, then it’s no.  That’s quite plain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your Mac Mini is in a cabinet or otherwise not easily accessible, you could use another Mac's optical drive and access it on the Mini, but otherwise, I can't think of any. I don't think there's a definitive answer to this.